# Reactive `material_select` is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

A user is presented with four select boxes in a form. Each select box must have a unique value, and these options come from the `Products` collection. When a value has been taken, the select should reactively change to show the remaining, untaken options.

My first class refers to the overarching form.

```
class SelectForm extends BlazeComponent {
  onCreated() {
    super.onCreated();
    this._selected = new Mongo.Collection(null);
    _.range(4).map(i => this._selected.insert({
      slot: i,
      product: undefined
    }));
  }
}
```

Then I have a class for each select box which reactively should re-run materialize's select functionality.

```
class SelectBox extends BlazeComponent {
  onRendered() {
    super.onRendered();
    this.autorun(() => {
      const selected = this.parentComponent()._selected.find();
      this.$('select').material_select();
    });
  }
  taken() {
    return this.parentComponent()._selected.find({
      product: { $ne: undefined }
    }).map(product => product._id);
  }
  options() {
    return Products.find({
      _id: { $nin: this.taken() }
    }).map(product => ({
      label: product.name,
      value: product._id
    }));
  }
}
```

However, this never re-renders the options, or changes their value.

Why is this? How do I reactively update a material select?

Comment: why don't you use autoform for this? it would be much easier to implement using `getField`.

Comment: because I only use it twice in the entire application

Comment: Could you try `null` instead of `undefined`